# How to remove Grand Total and Shipping & Handling from admin order create Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

How can i remove Grand Total and Shipping & Handling from admin order create page in magento 2.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed renderTotals function as follow.

```
public function renderTotals($area = null, $colspan = 1)

{
    $html = '';
    foreach ($this->getTotals() as $total) {
        if ($total->getArea() != $area && $area != -1 || $total->getCode() == 'tax' || $total->getCode() == 'shipping' || $total->getCode() == 'grand_total' || $total->getCode() == 'discount') {
            continue;
        }
        $html .= $this->renderTotal($total, $area, $colspan);
    }
    return $html;
}
```